# Calling an instance of same class inside class

Tags: python, sql, django, model, foreign-key-relationship

I have a model called Student in Django, I want a variable of student to be other students they are friends with.  For example:

Tim.friends_set.all() = Jim, Bob, Sam

What would my _____ be in this code?  Is there a way to do this without creating a new model?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    friends = models.________(Student, blank = True)
```

I image if I created a new model it would be something like:

```
class friends(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    friends = models.models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank = True)
```

Comment: Have you tried use ForeignKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ManyToManyField` with the argument `'self'`.

```
class Student(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
  friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank = True)
```

You may wish to consider if the relationship is [symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).

Comment: the symmetry is based on Nearest Neighbors, so their is the possibility of an instance where it might not be symmetrical.  Doubtful though.  When I call it with 'self', it says:

assert isinstance(to, six.string_types), "%s(%r) is invalid. First parameter to ManyToManyField must be either a model, a model name, or the string %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, to, RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT)
AssertionError: ManyToManyField(<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField>) is invalid. First parameter to ManyToManyField must be either a model, a model name, or the string u'self'

Comment: @Rob by default the relationship *will* be symmetrical - meaning if A is a friend of B, then B is also a friend of A.

Comment: Where are you referencing `Student`? Note the argument to the `ManyToMany` field is `'self'`, not `Student`

Comment: I copied and pasted it from what you wrote, so I'm not sure if its something elsewhere in my code or what.

Comment: @Rob remove blank=True

Comment: The sample I wrote above is valid - you can use that. Please add your new code to the question or ask a new question if you are still having problems.
Your error message suggests your first argument to `ManyToManyField` is incorrect (sounds like you are doing something like `models.ManyToManyField(many_to_many_field_instance)`)